# Setup Nagios check_clamd

Tags: nagios, clam

I'm getting a `(No output returned from plugin)` from a host and cannot understand why:

**Service on monitor server:**

```
# Check Clamd availability
define service {
    hostgroup_name                  clamd-servers
    service_description             ClamAV Daemon
    check_command                   check_nrpe!check_clamd
    use                             generic-service
    notification_interval           0 ; set > 0 if you want to be renotified
}
```

**Hosts on monitor:**

```
# Clamd Servers
define hostgroup {
        hostgroup_name  clamd-servers
        alias           ClamAV servers
        members         fsmvps
        }
```

**nrpe_local.fcfg on host fsmvps**

```
command[check_clamd]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_clamd -H /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
```

Running the command `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_clamd -H /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl` on the host will produce the following output as clam is up and running:

```
CLAMD OK - 0.000 second response time on socket /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl [PONG]|time=0.000219s;;;0.000000;10.000000
```

Clueless at the moment as to why no output is returned as I'm a beginner on Nagios.

Comment: When you run the command from the Nagios server, what is the response?

Comment: Hi Thanks. Managed to solve by changing clamav to run on TCP port 3310 and calling the check_clamd command directly. Should I add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your NRPE service wasn't setup right (sometimes it complains about ssl).

Running (as the nagios user) on your monitor server something like :

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H fsmvps check_clamd
```

Might help diagnose things.

It might be :

- Permissions (can the nagios user on fsmvps read /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl)
- check_nrpe needs the -n flag or a different port.
- you've not restarted nrpe on the fsmvps server after editing it's config.